# Getting random numbers on JTextField by pressing JButtom

Tags: java

I am quite new in java... Recently I have started gui works in java. I want to make a program which will give me a quadratic equation with random values of A , B and C in a `TextField` and in the next `TextField` it will just show the value of X's.

I can make a `MessageDialog` pop up and give the desired outputs but I cannot make this happen in the `TextField`s. In the `actionPerformed` method I have managed to set the desired results in first and second `JTextField` objects by using `setText()` but i cannot make them appear in the display.

My codes is:

```
package apple;
import apple.mouse2.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;


class mouse extends JFrame{
    String equ; String res;
    mouse2 m = new mouse2();
    JTextField eq; JTextField s;JButton g; JTextField eq1; JTextField s2;
    public mouse(){
    super("quadratic equation");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    g = new JButton("Generate");
    g.addActionListener(
    new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

            m.set();
            eq.setText(m.geteq());
            s.setText(m.getr());
        }
    }
    );    
    add(g);
    eq = new JTextField();
    eq.setEditable(false);
    add(eq);
    s = new JTextField(res);
    s.setEditable(false);
    add(s);
    }
}
```

in mouse2 class i just generated random values for A,B and C and calculated the values for X1 and X2.

Answer (score 0):

You have to revalidate(); the frame. If that doesn't work you also have to call repaint();

Answer (score 0):

Try to use validate() or revalidate() inside the event method

```
g.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        m.set();
        eq.setText(m.geteq());
        s.setText(m.getr());
        revalidate();
    }
});
```

Comment: that helped a lot